# Как сделать так, чтобы был доступ к методу вложенного класса, если объявлен только внешний класс Java

Tags: java, синтаксис

То есть если в классе Class есть вложенный класс innerClass с методом method() была возможна такая вещь:

```
Class class = new Class();
class.innerClass.method();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Прежде всего, не надо использовать зарезервированные слова в качестве имён переменных и названия классов из стандартной библиотеки в качестве имён классов вашей программы. Кроме того, стоит придерживаться [соглашения о стиле](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html). То, что член `innerClass` начинается с маленькой буквы, наводит на мысль, что это поле, а не вложенный класс.

Если `Inner` - это статический вложенный класс

```
class Outer {
    static class Inner {
        public void someMethod() {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

то код обращения к его методу может выглядеть так

```
Outer.Inner obj = new Outer.Inner();
obj.someMethod();
```

Если это внутренний класс

```
class Outer {
    class Inner {
        public void someMethod() {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

то так

```
Outer outerObj = new Outer();
Outer.Inner innerObj = outerObject.new Inner();
innerObj.someMethod();
```

Наиболее близкий код, к приведённому вами - это инстанцирование вложенного класса во внешнем и присвоение объекта полю

```
class Outer {
    public Inner innerObj = new Inner();

    static class Inner {
        public void someMethod() {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

тогда обращение к методу будет выглядеть так

```
Outer obj = new Outer();
obj.innerObj.someMethod();
```

Естественно, это возможно и с внутренним классом.

[Соответствующий раздел документации.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: спасибо большое